# Geting the photo sent from Facebook Messenger Charbot to Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, image-processing, facebook-messenger-bot, amazon-lex

Is there a way to receive or get the image sent from Facebook Messenger Chatbot to Amazon Lex?

Currently when I send an image to my chatbot in Facebook Messenger it doesn't reply or have the "seen" status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

AWS Lex is a conversation bot that only responds to voice and text.

Comment: To be more specific, this is true when you currently integrate Messenger directly to Lex in the Channels section. However, you can setup a "bot server" which asks as a layer between FB and Lex. The "bot server" can then handle images and other messages from FB. It can use PostText to talk to Lex.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup an API Gateway which will connect to your FB bot.
This API Gateway will forward the request to Lambda function, which will do pre-processing, image processing etc, then forward the request to Lex using PostText (if required) or directly reply to your FB bot. Lex, then, can call one more Lambda function as it normally does.

Your architecture will then look like below image:
[image]
Instead of Twillio you can use Facebook, and in the Lambda function you can decide which requests to forward to Lex and where you need to apply image processing or anything.

See [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/integrate-your-amazon-lex-bot-with-any-messaging-service/) for detailed information.

Hope it helps.